# customizable data filter

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

We currently have a WPF application showing some 3D schema and we have made a custom filter that enables to display only items that have certain properties. You can basically add new items to the filter and each item has a combobox to select what property you want to filter on and what values the property must have. We use this filter in the WPF  views, but we also have a COM interface though which we can use it as well, so the filter can be used without a GUI as well.

We are trying to replace the filter with an off the shelf solution if possible. Does anyone know of any existing products with that sort of functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are going to use Telerik's expression editor. It has an Expression property which returns a LambdaExpression and you can set the current expression by setting the ExpressionText property. The editor then displays the new expression.

See here:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/wpf/expression-editor/radexpressioneditor-persisting-of-expressions.aspx